# Restrict insert permissions on a single table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, permissions

I have a MySQL table that needs restricted permissions for `INSERT`.

Specifically, I have written a stored function that handles all `INSERT` operations, and I need to restrict permissions so ***ONLY*** this stored function is allowed to insert rows in this specific table.

***"But why would you do that?"***

Because MySQL doesn't support Microsoft's `INSTEAD OF INSERT` triggers, and a custom stored function/procedure for insertion is the only viable workaround.
And I need it to *work* like a trigger - *guaranteed* to execute for every `INSERT` operation, with no exceptions or loopholes.

The function returns 0 if no errors, 1 if invalid parameters, 2 if unique index collision, etc.
(Or maybe the function will include an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement, I haven't decided yet.)

***"But why do you need INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers?"***

For the same reason that Microsoft SQL Server developers need it ... because it does the job that needs to be done ...
Specifically, because my code includes `GET_LOCK` *before* insertion, and `RELEASE_LOCK` *after* insertion ... and I don't want a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to end without releasing the lock (seems like a very bad idea).

Comment: Various SQL implementations handle transactions in different ways. We may be able to help you better if you describe your requirement rather than simply referring to SQL Server's transaction semantics. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create MySQL stored functions (and stored procedures) including the clause `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` .  Then, they'll [run with the permissions of the definer, not the user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-objects-security.html).  Your definition might look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
       SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tbl whatever....;
END;
```

When you do this, log in to MySQL with an administrator's account, not a user's account.

Then use MySQL's permission system to grant INSERT access for that table to the administrator's account and [revoke it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partial-revokes.html) for other users' accounts.

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE mydatabase.mytable TO admin;
REVOKE INSERT ON mydatabase.mytable FROM user1;
REVOKE INSERT ON mydatabase.mytable FROM user2;
```

Then, `INSERT` queries from other users' accounts will fail, but the stored function will succeed. This is more-or-less conventional SQL stored code privilege handling.

MySQL triggers, of any flavor, can't start or end transactions.